# is there periost beneath the articular cartilage?

Tags: joints

I have read that : "The articular capsule surrounds the joint and is continuous with the periosteum of articulating bones." Does that mean that the periost forms the articular capsule in joints and there is no periost beneath the articular cartilage? Or is there additional periost beneath the articular cartilage?

Thanks a lot!